# Why is 11ty compiling everything to the output directory *except* index.njk?

Tags: node.js, static-site, eleventy

Running `npx eleventy --serve` writes all my template files to the output directory except for `index.njk`. So `localhost:8080` throws a `Cannot GET /` error but `localhost:8080/about/` shows me my `about.md` file, and so on for all other files. It can't be an issue with processing `.njk` files because other `.njk` files are showing up fine at their respective permalinks.

This is a new problem and as far as I can tell, the only thing I changed is I created a git repository in the folder. Running debug doesn't show any errors. It does show that 11ty is *finding* `index.njk`, and adding it to map...

```
Eleventy:TemplateWriter Found: [ './blog/index.njk' ] +0ms
Eleventy:Template getMappedDate: using file created time for './blog/index.html' of 2020-03-08T22:48:56.628Z (from 1583707736628.0034) +1ms
Eleventy:TemplateWriter ./blog/index.html added to map. +2ms
```

...but it just doesn't end up on the list of files written. I've tried adding a `pathPrefix`, moving `.eleventy.js` around and changing the input directory, changing `index.njk` to `.md` and `.html`, and triple-checking my `.eleventyignore` and `.gitignore`, but I'm stumped.

My file structure looks like this.

```
├── .git
├── _site
├── blog
|   ├── _includes
|   ├── _data 
|   ├── assets
|   ├── _posts
|   |   ├── 2016-08-08-i-published-a-pattern.md
|   |   ├── 2016-08-20-pyukumuku.md
|   |   └── style-guide.md
|   ├── about.md
|   ├── index.njk
|   ├── tag.njk
|   ├── tagslist.njk
└── .eleventy.js
```

And the relevant portion of my `.eleventy.js` looks like this.

```
eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy("assets");
return {
    passthroughFileCopy: true,
    markdownTemplateEngine: "njk",
    templateFormats: ["html", "njk", "md"],
    dir: {
        input: "blog",
        output: "_site",
        include: "_includes"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Update: Renaming `index.njk` to something else and creating a brand-new `index.njk` with identical content creates an `index.html` file in the output directory, but it is blank. Tried moving the content of `index.njk` to `blog.njk` and making `index.njk` just text with a link to `blog`. Now `blog.njk` is the file that does not write to output. The OG `index.njk` is just a `for` loop with front-matter pagination in order to display blog posts, so it looks like there may be something up with that code?

Comment: Did you see any error messages on the console?

Comment: Nope, no error messages either normally or with debug.

Comment: I get the same issue when I use frontmatter pagination in the index page and no post have been created yet. I am still looking for a workaround, other than having a sample post to avoid the issue...

Comment: could you post your  `index.njk` frontmatter please? is there something like `data: collections.post`?

Comment: Sounds like the `index.njk` file is causing issues, could you post the contents of that? or at least the yaml frontmatter

Comment: Late comment but for future Googlers : I had the same problem and starting from a blank `index.njk` solved it. It seems that an error occurs at compile time but is not shown resulting in the file being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue today. When I [ran](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/debugging/) `DEBUG=Eleventy* npx @11ty/eleventy`, I saw this in the output:

```
Eleventy:EleventyFiles >>> When processing .gitignore/.eleventyignore, Eleventy does not currently support negative patterns but encountered one: +0ms
  Eleventy:EleventyFiles >>> !/src +0ms
  Eleventy:EleventyFiles Follow along at https://github.com/11ty/eleventy/issues/693 to track support. +0ms
  Eleventy:EleventyFiles >>> When processing .gitignore/.eleventyignore, Eleventy does not currently support negative patterns but encountered one: +0ms
  Eleventy:EleventyFiles >>> !/src/style.css +0ms
  Eleventy:EleventyFiles Follow along at https://github.com/11ty/eleventy/issues/693 to track support. +0ms
```

Going through the issue on github, I came across [this](https://github.com/11ty/eleventy/issues/693#issuecomment-632996225):
`eleventyConfig.setUseGitIgnore(false);`as a possible solution. I did have a negative pattern in my **.gitignore**, and adding that line to **.eleventy.js** fixed the problem.